# Insert/Update trigger in sql server to check values

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and triggers. I have an existing trigger i need to customise. There are two tables Products (which contains the total amount of products in the stock. Quantity) and OrdersLines (which contains all information about orders. an example row would would have OrderID, ProductID and Amount in it)
When I make an order product amount is reserved.
I need the trigger to to check if new ordered amount doesnt go above the Quantity. If it does, throw RAISERROR, if not, let the transaction continue.

I'm having trouble with identifying number of total order to check against the Quantity in stock.

Trigger is for OrdersLines table
I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT *
            FROM Products AS p
            JOIN inserted AS i
            ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
            JOIN OrdersLines AS o
            ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
            WHERE (SUM(o.Amount) + i.Amount) <= p.Quantity)
BEGIN 
    GOTO ContinueTransaction
END ELSE BEGIN
    GOTO RollbackTransaction
    END
```

but I think this is not correct. Also in ELSE i need RAISERROR to inform that order wasn't added but I'm not sure how. There are arguments to be put there and its confusing to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger CheckOrderAmount 
On orderLines 
for insert, update
As 
Begin
Set NoCount On;

   if exists (Select * from inserted I
                 join products p
                    on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
              group by i.ProductID 
              having SUM(i.Amount) > p.Quantity)
    begin
      rollback transaction
      raiserror("There are not enough items in inventory", 16, 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: doesnt inserted table consist only of inserted (new) rows? or in other words it doesnt have rows that existed before insert? 
edit: and also wouldnt ur example rollback transaction if there are enough of items in stock? and also, if its not too much, why "16, 1"?

Comment: Yes, but it has all columns, including those you haven't changed. And aren't you updating the quantity in Products table after inserting the order? if you are, then you just need to make sure that these new orders do not exceed *current* quantity remaining, right?

Comment: And it only rolls back transaction if sum of amount in inserted (new) orders exceeds current quantity.  the rollback is inside the begin end block that is conditional on the exists being true.

Comment: But I forgot this is based on a `Sum()` so the exists needs to be an aggregate (group By) query and the predicate needs to be in a `Having` clause not a `where` clause. I edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: Quantity in Products is not updated when inserting the order, at least for now. Thats why i tried joining 3 tables

Comment: So, knowing that, can I join a third table and have a condition like in my attempt? 
also, dont I need to declare `SUM` in the beggining with `SELECT` as in `SELECT SUM(o.Amount) FROM OrdersLines o` before using it in `HAVING` ?

Comment: If quantity is not updated, then this must be the original quantity? How can that be? What happens when you run out of items and actually need to physically add more items to the warehouse? DO you update the quantity then? What do you update it to? You have to keep the quantity in Products table accurate as to how many items are in inventory. How else can this work?

Comment: And, no, you do not need to declare `Sum` in the select clause to use it in the Having clause.

Comment: And back to updating `products.quantity`.  You can't of course update it in the same SQL statement that inserts the order, but it must be updated using another SQL Statement (an Update statement), as part of the same transaction that performs the order insert, immediately after the order insert. Otherwise this process will not work. At any time that an order is inserted, the value in the quantity column must accurately represent the number of items in inventory when the order was placed (before it is posted).

Comment: i understand and agree with that logic, but its not for a real life application its a learning excercise and those were the conditions. I've solved it, though not very gracefully I guess. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with following.
for insert trigger:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM atbv_Sales_Products p 
            JOIN inserted i
            ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
            JOIN atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
            ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
            GROUP BY i.ProductID, i.Amount, p.Quantity
            HAVING (SUM(ol.Amount) + i.Amount) > p.Quantity)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProductName NVARCHAR(60)
            SET @ProductName = (SELECT p.ProductName 
                                    FROM atbv_Sales_Products p
                                    JOIN inserted i 
                                    ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID)
            RAISERROR ('----There is not enough items (%s) left----', 18, 1, @ProductName) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
            RETURN
END
```

for update trigger:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM atbv_Sales_Products p 
            JOIN atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
            ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
            GROUP BY p.ProductID, ol.Amount, p.Quantity
            HAVING SUM(ol.Amount) > p.Quantity)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProductName NVARCHAR(60)
            SET @ProductName = (SELECT p.ProductName 
                                    FROM atbv_Sales_Products p
                                    JOIN atbv_Sales_OrdersLines ol
                                    ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
                                    GROUP BY p.ProductID, ol.Amount, p.Quantity, p.ProductName
                                    HAVING SUM(ol.Amount) > p.Quantity)
            RAISERROR ('----There is not enough items (%s) left----', 18, 1, @ProductName) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
            RETURN
END
```